# Comma delimited list - how to obtain the length?

Tags: loops, comma-separated-list

It's simple. I have a list like `{0,1,54,1,3}` as input argument to a command in making. How can I obtain the length of this list? Something like

```
\length(#1)
```

where `#1` is the list.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 24):

My first LaTeX3 answer! Yay! `:)`

The `l3clist` package has a lot of built-in commands to deal with comma-separated lists. Here's an attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \countItems { m } {
    \clist_count:N #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand \countInlineItems { m } {
    \clist_count:n {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\mylist{0,1,54,1,3}

This list has \countInlineItems{0,1,54,1,3} elements.

And the same list has \countItems{\mylist} elements.

\end{document}
```

Please note that we have two different usages: one for a stored list (e.g, `\mylist`) and one for an inline list. Thanks to Joseph for point the flaws in my code. `:)`

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: Since this is LaTeX3, I won't dare assume that this is ok (although I tested it and it seems to work): A trick I have been using with non-LaTeX3 to have a single macro for these two cases is to ONLY use the one that works on macro defined lists, and  do an `\edef\TempList{#1}` and then use `TempList` instead of #1. Then the macro is only ever working on a macro defined list, and you don't need to think about which version to call when using it...  Perhaps there are inherent problems, but seems to be ok so far. All the solutions I posted using a `\foreach` in a macro should already do this.

Comment: @PeterGrill You should _never_ use `\edef` on unknown input in LaTeX2e: use `\protected@edef`. Even that may be risky, which is why we take care to define the difference between a variable and 'some tokens'. Also, if you want an expandable solution then `\edef` is out in any form.

Comment: Shouldn’t the second `\countInlineItems` be `\countItems`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: silly me, I forgot about that! `:)` Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

A loop and a counter:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\length}[1]{%
    \@tempcnta\z@
    \@for\@tempa:=#1\do{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne}%
    The length of the list #1 is \the\@tempcnta.%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\length{0,1,54,1,3}

\def\mylist{0,1,54,1,3}
\length\mylist
\end{document}
```

### Output

> The length of the list 0,1,54,1,3 is 5.

Answer (score 9):

### Package `xstring`, counting empty elements

A solution using package `xstring`. It also counts elements that are empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\commalength}[1]{%
  \StrCount{#1,}{,}%
}
\begin{document}
\verb|{0,1,54,1,3}| has length \commalength{0,1,54,1,3}.

\verb|{,,}| has length \commalength{,,}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Package `kvsetkeys`, counting non-empty elements

The parser `\comma@parse` of package `kvsetkeys` removes an optional space before and after an entry and removes empty entries.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\commalength}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \count@=0 %
    \comma@parse{#1}{%
      \advance\count@ by 1 %
      \@gobble
    }%
    \the\count@
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\verb|{0,1,54,1,3}| has length \commalength{0,1,54,1,3}.

\verb|{,,}| has length \commalength{,,}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Let's try `etoolbox`.

This use the loop and counter approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{itemcounter}%
\newcommand{\length}[1]{%
    \setcounter{itemcounter}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{itemcounter}\@gobble{##1}}%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
    \theitemcounter%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\length{1}\qquad \length{1,2}\qquad \length{1,2,3,f,t,w,x,y,z}
\end{document}
```

The command `\@gobble` discards its argument.

Comment: Why don't you just do `\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{itemcounter}}` when gobble it anyway?