# Longtable: Variable or switch to determine if row is the first or last one of the current page

Tags: longtable, arydshln

I am currently struggling with the longtable package and horizontal lines that should visually separate rows. The thing is that I do not want to display bottom lines on the last row of each particular page and a top line on the first row of each succeeding page. My question would be if there is any variable or switch of the longtable code that i can use to determine (inside my `rowend` command) if this is true and then suppress the execution of `hdashline`? I know of the variable `\LT@rows` but what I have tried so far didn't give me any results.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\newcommand{\rowend}{%
  \tabularnewline%
  % Determine here if it is the last row of the current page or first row of next page
  % If it is the last row of the current page, don't make a bottom dashed line.
  % If it is the first row of a succeeding page, don't make a top row (although I have no idea why that line is actually drawn ...
  \hdashline%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|r|c|p{2cm}|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rowend

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such switch (and no direct way to provide one) the main idea of longtable is that it uses a standard TeX asynchronous output routine to do the page breaking. This means that, as in a normal text page, the macro layer has really no idea about what page any bit of text will finally land on.

It would be possible to use a two pass system using `\pageref` (or `\pdfsavepos`, or wrappers such as zref) to detect if one row is on a different page from the previous and so in that case omit the rule, or (perhaps) you could adjust the rule to have a special depth (say 1sp) and detect that and remove it in the output routine.

An alternative would be to use `supertabular` instead of `longtable` that does the page breaking "by hand" within the table macros measuring the height and then stopping the table forcing a break and starting a new one internally. 
In such a system it is much easier to "know" that you are the last row of a page.

Comment: David, thank you for your insightful explanation. The point with the asynchronous output routine makes totally sense to, although I'm a little bit overwhelmed by how to achieve it with pageref, as I'm dynamically creating the table as you suggested in this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161078/46403.

Comment: @hetsch idea would be that at the end of a row that you want to follow with an optional \hline do `\label{some-generated-name-a}\\\myhline\label{some-generated-name-b}` then define `myhline` to do an `\hline` unless both the labels -a and -b are defined from the previous run and `\pageref` shows they are on separate pages, in which case omit the hline.

Comment: Thousand thanks, I'll definitely give it a try this evening!