# Display a sequence of materials with chemical symbols

Tags: mhchem, chemistry

I frequently have to describe a sequence of materials in a layer stack such as the following:

> Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co−Fe−B/MgO/Co−Fe−B/Ta/Ru/Au

The dash indicates an alloy of unspecified composition. My question is how to properly typeset this in LaTeX.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

The layer stack consist of \ce{Ta}/\ce{Cu}/\ce{Ta}/\ce{Cu}/\ce{Co-Fe-B}/\ce{MgO}/\ce{Co-Fe-B}/\ce{Ta}/\ce{Ru}/\ce{Au} and all layers are sputtered in a bla bla bla

Co-Fe
\end{document}
```

[image: layer stack]

However, there are several things wrong with this.

1. No line break inserted after one of the slashes
2. The dash becomes a bond (an em dash, I believe)
3. The frequent use of `\ce` looks awkward and the code is close to be unreadable.

Is there a better way to do this (with mhchem)? Please note, that the use of the dashes as well as the slashes is suggested by most publishers (in our field of research) and should not be replaced by other symbols.

Comment: You can use `\slash` instead of `/` if you want to allow a linebreak after a slash. If you write `\ce{Co}-\ce{Fe}-\ce{B}` you can avoid the bond problem (but of course you'll have even more `\ce`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you scroll down to my code, please notice that just because this code works does not mean that it is a good way to do so.

In general, there is a data structure called "comma list". Comma list plays a role in LaTeX-programming. For example while using `geometry` we may say `\usepackage[top=2cm,left=3cm]{geometry}`. In this case, `top=2cm,left=3cm` is a comma list that contains two items: `top=2cm` and `left=3cm`. (They are separated by comma, hence the name.) (And then `top=2cm` is interpreted as a key-value pair: `top` the key and `2cm` the value.)

Similarly, your notation is indeed a "nested comma list". The outer level is called "stack" with `/` being its separator. The inner level is called "layer" with `-` being its separator. So all you need to do is to mimic [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87407/iterating-through-comma-separated-arguments) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105885/comma-delimited-list-how-to-obtain-the-length) to iterate over your nested slash-dash list.

Since your request is relatively simple (only letters and numbers involved), a short TeX code is enough to illustrate how to deal with your <del>comma list</del> nested slash-dash list:

- First of all `\CE` takes an argument, the complete list, and passes it to `CEii`.
- `\CEii`  takes two arguments separating by `/`. So the first argument is the substring before the first `/`. The substring after becomes the second argument. For example `Co-Fe-B/MgO/Co-Fe-B` is divided into `Co-Fe-B` and `MgO/Co-Fe-B`.
- Now the first argument `Co-Fe-B` should be the first layer, pass it to `\Ce`.
- If the second argument is not empty, then there are more layers coming. Insert a `\newslash`.
- Treat the second argument, the other layers `MgO/Co-Fe-B`, as a new list and start from the beginning. (`MgO/Co-Fe-B` becomes `MgO` and `Co-Fe-B`. Both of them are passed to `\Ce` in sequence. Another `\newslash` is inserted between them.)
- `\Ce` and `Ceii` do the same job as `CE` and `CEii`. The difference is that it divides the string according to `-` and inserts `\newdash`. (`Co-Fe-B` becomes `Co`, `Fe` and `B`.) And pass these elements to `\ce` in sequence.
- (MgO is not an element ... my bad)
- It is your job to redefine `\newskash` and `\newdash`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\def\newslash{///}
\def\newdash{---}
\newif\ifmoreelements
\newif\ifmorelayers

\def\Ce#1{%
    \def\templayer{#1}%
    \loop%
        \expandafter\Ceii\templayer-=%
        \expandafter\ce\expandafter{\tempfirstelement}%
    \ifmoreelements%
        \newdash%
        \expandafter\Cei\tempotherelements=%
    \repeat}
\def\Cei#1-={%
    \def\templayer{#1}}
\def\Ceii#1-#2={%
    \def\tempfirstelement{#1}\def\tempotherelements{#2}%
    \ifx\tempotherelements\empty\moreelementsfalse\else\moreelementstrue\fi}
\def\CE#1{%
    \def\tempstack{#1}%
    \loop%
        \expandafter\CEii\tempstack/+%
        {\expandafter\Ce\expandafter{\tempfirstlayer}}%
    \ifmorelayers%
        \newslash%
        \expandafter\CEi\tempotherlayers+%
    \repeat}
\def\CEi#1/+{%
    \def\tempstack{#1}}
\def\CEii#1/#2+{%
    \def\tempfirstlayer{#1}\def\tempotherlayers{#2}%
    \ifx\tempotherlayers\empty\morelayersfalse\else\morelayerstrue\fi}

\CE{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co-Fe-B/MgO/Co-Fe-B/Ta/Ru/Au}

\end{document}
```

### About *Good* way

Sometimes I hear people saying that we should never use `\def`. And the reason is clear: using `TeX` syntax is in some sense *dangerous*. For example if one says `\CE{-==-+//+-==-}`, it will not work as expected. Besides, there are some *appearance* issues. For example `\CE{ Ta // Cu }` will call `\ce{ Ta }` and `\ce{ Cu }` with spaces while `\CE` should ignore all spaces around commas.

Nevertheless, it is all up to you. If you KNOW your code will never be like `\CE{-==-+//+-==-}` and you do like this simple way, then use it. But If you are seeking a way that is powerful and safe, say `\DeclareCommaListParser\CE[/][-]{blahblahblah}`, then give `xparse` a chance.

For me, `xparse` is complicated so far. However if someday LaTeX3 released and those commands are well-documented, I may not answer questions with `def` anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by 'because this code works does not mean that it is a good way to do so'? (a) You know, that this code misuses LaTeX in some way. (b) It might or might not be a good way to do it.

Comment: @Andy I add some words to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For those using [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) instead of [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) there is a quick solution. I suffices to replace `/` be `\slash` to allow line breaks after the slash. Since `chemformula` already has a mechanism for replacing input symbols with output symbols in compounds we only need to access it:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemformula_new_compound_property:nn #1#2
  { \prop_put_if_new:Nnn \l__chemformula_cmpd_prop {#1} {#2} }

\NewDocumentCommand \NewChemCompoundProperty { mm }
  { \chemformula_new_compound_property:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now all that's left is saying `\NewChemCompoundProperty{/}{\slash}`. This makes use of an internal variable so it is not entirely safe but I'm inclined to add something similar to the package.

As for the `-` being transformed into single bonds – the same is true for `chemformula` but using `chemformula`'s `"..."` syntax can help here. Or – using the new command one could say `\NewChemCompoundProperty{:}{-}` (or something):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula,mhchem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% I might add this to chemformula:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemformula_new_compound_property:nn #1#2
  { \prop_put_if_new:Nnn \l__chemformula_cmpd_prop {#1} {#2} }

\NewDocumentCommand \NewChemCompoundProperty { mm }
  { \chemformula_new_compound_property:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewChemCompoundProperty{/}{\slash}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Bla.  The layer stack consists of \ch{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co "-" Fe "-" B/MgO/Co "-"
  Fe "-" B/Ta/Ru/Au} and all layers are sputtered in a bla bla bla

% or even:
\NewChemCompoundProperty{:}{-}

Bla.  The layer stack consists of
\ch{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co:Fe:B/MgO/Co:Fe:B/Ta/Ru/Au} and all layers are sputtered in
a bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update** Version 4.10 (2015/03/16) supports this directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}[2015/03/16]

\NewChemCompoundProperty{/}{\slash}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Bla.  The layer stack consists of \ch{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co "-" Fe "-" B/MgO/Co "-"
  Fe "-" B/Ta/Ru/Au} and all layers are sputtered in a bla bla bla

% or even:
\NewChemCompoundProperty{:}{-}

Bla.  The layer stack consists of
\ch{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co:Fe:B/MgO/Co:Fe:B/Ta/Ru/Au} and all layers are sputtered in
a bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could work with the new RegExp engine. Out of curiosity, I tried it and found a solution. It's a weird mix of old and new syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\stackslash{\text{/}\allowbreak}
\newcommand*\stackdash{\text{-}\allowbreak}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\stack[1] {
  \tl_new:N \l_my_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_my_tl { \exp_not:N \ce { #1 } }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \/ } { \cE] \c{stackslash} \c{ce}\cB[ } \l_my_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \- } { \cE] \c{stackdash} \c{ce}\cB[ } \l_my_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_my_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

The layer stack consist of \stack{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co-Fe-B/MgO/Co-Fe-B/Ta/Ru/Au} and all layers are sputtered in a bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Basically, it takes `A/B/C-D/E` and transforms it into `\ce{A}\stackslash\ce{B}\stackslash\ce{C}\stackdash\ce{D}\stackslash\ce{E}`.

Comment: I incorporated this idea of mine into mhchem 3.21. A configurable `\cesplit` command is provided. Search the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) for the "Layer Stack" example.

Answer (score 2):

With mhchem 3.21, you can use the `\cesplit` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\stackslash{\text{/}\allowbreak}
\newcommand*\stackhyphen{\text{-}\allowbreak}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\cesplit{{\/}{\c{stackslash}}{-}{\c{stackhyphen}}}{#1}}
The layer stack consists of \stack{Ta/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co-Fe-B/MgO/Co-Fe-B/Ta/Ru/Au} and all layers are sputtered in \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a small Lua snippet demonstrating different approach which passes plain text (ending by space) to Lua, uses regular expressions and passes output back to the TeX engine. It extends a series of text characters except slashes and minuses to the `\ce` command, changes divis to endash and adds `\allowbreak` command after each slash.

Let the input is: `Cu/Ta/H2O/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co-Fe-B/MgO/Co-Fe-B/Ta/Ru/Au`.

The modified text looks like this: `\ce{Cu}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ta}/\allowbreak{}\ce{H2O}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Cu}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ta}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Cu}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Co}--\allowbreak{}\ce{Fe}--\allowbreak{}\ce{B}/\allowbreak{}\ce{MgO}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Co}--\allowbreak{}\ce{Fe}--\allowbreak{}\ce{B}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ta}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ru}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Au}`.

We execute `lualatex mal-chem.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function malstr(text)
text=string.gsub(text, "[^/-]+", "\\ce{%1}")
text=string.gsub(text, "%-", "--\\allowbreak{}") 
-- -- or --\\allowbreak{}
text=string.gsub(text, "/", "/\\allowbreak{}")
tex.print(text); print(text)
end -- of function malstr
\end{luacode*}
\def\nobonds#1 {\directlua{malstr([[#1]])} }
\lipsum[1]\par
The layer stack consist of \nobonds Cu/Ta/H2O/Cu/Ta/Cu/Co-Fe-B/MgO/Co-Fe-B/Ta/Ru/Au and all layers are sputtered in...
% result is: \ce{Cu}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ta}/\allowbreak{}\ce{H2O}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Cu}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ta}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Cu}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Co}--\allowbreak{}\ce{Fe}--\allowbreak{}\ce{B}/\allowbreak{}\ce{MgO}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Co}--\allowbreak{}\ce{Fe}--\allowbreak{}\ce{B}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ta}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Ru}/\allowbreak{}\ce{Au}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting figure]