# Setting a counter to a value obtained by expansion

Tags: macros, counters, expansion

I use the `glossaries` and `minitoc` packages. Minitocs are generated for all glossaries printed in the table of content, eg with the `toc` option for the glossaries package. When one prints the glossaries before the chapters, the not-yet printed minitoc of the glossaries are printed instead of the chapter ones, effectively offsetting the minitocs with regards to the chapters.

Manually, this can be solved by offsetting the `mtc` counter of the minitocs, eg `\addtocounter{mtc}{2}` if there are 2 glossaries (acronyms + actual glossary for example).

I'm trying to automatically do that shift to embed it in a package. First is getting the number of glossaries. The glossaries package define the macro `\@glo@types` as a comma-separated list of the names of the glossaries defined.
Thus, I can print the number of glossaries with:
`\expandafter\listLength\expandafter{\@glo@types}`
where the `\listLength` macro, inspired by this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105886/60987) and relying on etoolbox, is:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{listlength@cnt}
\newcommand*{\listlength@add}[1]{\stepcounter{listlength@cnt}}
\newcommand*{\listLength}[1]{%
    \setcounter{listlength@cnt}{0}%
    \forcsvlist{\listlength@add}{#1}%
    \thelistlength@cnt%
}
\makeatother
```

However, when I try to use the value in the `addtocounter` command, it doesn't work anymore. For the same example:

- `\expandafter\listLength\expandafter{\@glo@types}` prints 2
- `\addtocounter{mtc}{\expandafter\listLength\expandafter{\@glo@types}}` outputs a "Missing number" error. I tried with different combinations of `\expandafter` before/in that command, but as you might have picked up, I have troubles with the expansion process.

So, how can I offset a counter to a value derived by expansion?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries

\begin{filecontents}{glossary.tex}
    \newacronym{nraa}{NRAA}{Not Really An Acronym}
    \newglossaryentry{stuff}{
      name={stuff},
      description={a test}%
    }
\end{filecontents}
\loadglsentries{glossary}

% macro to count args of csv-list
\makeatletter
\newcounter{listlength@cnt}
\newcommand*{\listlength@add}[1]{\stepcounter{listlength@cnt}}
\newcommand*{\listLength}[1]{%
    \setcounter{listlength@cnt}{0}%
    \forcsvlist{\listlength@add}{#1}%                        % from etoolbox
    \thelistlength@cnt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \dominitoc            % Generating mini-toc
    \tableofcontents
    \glsaddall            % adding all glossary entries for the test
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printglossary[type=main]
    \addtocounter{mtc}{2} % manual offset
    \newpage
    \makeatletter
    number of glossaries:
    \expandafter{\expandafter\listLength\expandafter{\@glo@types} % prints 2
    %\addtocounter{mtc}{\expandafter\listLength\expandafter{\@glo@types}}
    % results in error, missing number
    \makeatother

    \chapter{chap1}
      chapter's toc is:
      \minitoc

      Content is:
      \section{s1}
        \subsection{s11}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code into a minimum (non)working example (starting with `\documentclass`, including packages, etc.), to help those wanting to help you.

Comment: Sounds like a good task for `expl3`'s `\exp_args:no` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\listLength` command doesn't work by pure expansion; you should say

```
\newcommand*{\listLength}[1]{%
    \setcounter{listlength@cnt}{0}%
    \forcsvlist{\listlength@add}{#1}%
}
```

as the definition of `\listLength` and then

```
\listLength{\@glo@types}%
\addtocounter{mtc}{\value{listlength@cnt}}%
```

in the code.

There's a much slicker way with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries

\begin{filecontents}{glossary.tex}
    \newacronym{nraa}{NRAA}{Not Really An Acronym}
    \newglossaryentry{stuff}{
      name={stuff},
      description={a test}%
    }
\end{filecontents}
\loadglsentries{glossary}

% macro to count args of csv-list
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\listLength}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \dominitoc            % Generating mini-toc
    \tableofcontents
    \glsaddall            % adding all glossary entries for the test
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printglossary[type=main]
    \addtocounter{mtc}{2}% manual offset
    \newpage
    number of glossaries:
    \makeatletter
    \listLength{\@glo@types} % prints 2
    \addtocounter{mtc}{\listLength{\@glo@types}}
    \themtc
    \makeatother

    \chapter{chap1}
      chapter's toc is:
      \minitoc

      Content is:
      \section{s1}
        \subsection{s11}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the value of `mtc` is 3, after the code has been executed.

The `\clist_count:n` command is fully expandable, your `\listLength` isn't.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'll hold on going into latex3 for now but I'll soon have some time available. Is there some kind of comprehensive guide for it, like the not so short introduction to latex2e?

Comment: @luneart Not yet; but `texdoc interface3` has pretty much all of it.